# MPAndroidChart: ( Stacked BarChart ) can't set up new ValueFormatter

Tags: android, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

I'm learning to use MPAndroidChart to create a stacked BarChart. 
Following this guide: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/The-AxisValueFormatter-interface

I've set up new class implements that interface and set new format like that.

```
barChart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(new MyXAxisValueFormatter(arrayLabel));
```

But Android studio shows an error: the method setValueFormatter need a ValueFormatter as parameter. IDE suggest that MyXAxisValueFormatter needs to extends ValueFormatter. I also do that but it doesn't work.

I'd appreciate it if anyone can help me out.

MyXAxisValueFormatter.java

```
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.AxisBase;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.formatter.IAxisValueFormatter;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.formatter.ValueFormatter;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class MyXAxisValueFormatter  implements IAxisValueFormatter {

    private String[] mValues;


    public MyXAxisValueFormatter(String[] values) {
        this.mValues = values;
    }


    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
        // "value" represents the position of the label on the axis (x or y)
        return mValues[(int) value];
    }

    /** this is only needed if numbers are returned, else return 0 */

    public int getDecimalDigits() { return 0; }
}
```

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnyEt.png)

Code I've used to setup chart:

```
barChart = root.findViewById(R.id.barChart);
                barChart.setTouchEnabled(true);
                barChart.setPinchZoom(true);
                barChart.clear();

                BarDataSet dataSet;
                ArrayList<BarEntry> values = new ArrayList<>();


                Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
                Calendar end = start.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
                Calendar dateCounter = start;
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");

                ArrayList<String> xAxisLabel = new ArrayList<>();
                int i = 0;

                while(dateCounter.compareTo(end) <= 0) {




                    values.add(new BarEntry(
                            i,
                            new float[]{0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0},
                            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.star)));

                    xAxisLabel.add(i,sdf.format(dateCounter.getTime()));
                    i++;
                    dateCounter.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
                }

                if (barChart.getData() != null &&
                        barChart.getData().getDataSetCount() > 0) {
                    dataSet = (BarDataSet) barChart.getData().getDataSetByIndex(0);
                    dataSet.setValues(values);
                    barChart.getData().notifyDataChanged();
                    barChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    dataSet = new BarDataSet(values, "test chart");
                    dataSet.setDrawIcons(false);
                    dataSet.setColors(getColors());
                    dataSet.setStackLabels(new String[]{"A", "B", "C", "D"});

                    ArrayList<IBarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
                    dataSets.add(dataSet);

                    BarData data = new BarData(dataSets);
                    data.setValueFormatter(new StackedValueFormatter(true, "", 1));
                    data.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE) ;
                    //data.setValueFormatter(new FlooringValueFormatter(2, 0.5f));
                    barChart.setData(data);
                }
                String[] arrayLabel = new String[xAxisLabel.size()];
                for(int count = 0; count < xAxisLabel.size(); count++){
                    arrayLabel[count] = xAxisLabel.get(count);
                }

                barChart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(new MyXAxisValueFormatter(arrayLabel));


                barChart.setFitBars(false);
                barChart.invalidate();
```

Comment: Please share MyXAxisValueFormatter and stack trace

Comment: i have edited. When i extends ValueFormatter then there are no more warning but the labels did not show as arrayLabel ( which is a string array )

Comment: I added an answer. How did you add barentries ?

Comment: My barentries ist an arrayList like this : (0, 10); ( 1, 15); (2, 20 )....

Comment: and labels ist an array like this: ( 0, label1); ( 1, label2)

Comment: Could you share your code?

Comment: updated my question

Comment: How do you use this line =>  Calendar end = start.add(Calendar.DATE, 1); no such use like this

Comment: I know. Just want to increment the datecounter. But it doesn't matter. I checked the barentries and xAxisLabel. The values are correct. But somehow the xAxis is not formatted with the new Formatter.

Comment: I edited my answer. I think, the  problem is axis position.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
extends ValueFormatter
```

instead of

```
implements IAxisValueFormatter
```

and change this method:

```
@Override
public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
    if((int) value < 0 && (int) value > mValues.length - 1){
       return "";
    }

    return mValues[(int) value];
}
```

Your barEntries should be like this:

```
ArrayList<BarEntry> barEntries = new ArrayList<>();
barEntries.add(new BarEntry(0, value1);
barEntries.add(new BarEntry(1, value2);
```

Set axis position like this:

```
barChart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(new MyXAxisValueFormatter(arrayLabel));
barChart.getXAxis().setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
```

Comment: I got it works now. Switch from MPandroidchart version 3.1.0 to 3.1.0-alpha. Thank for your help btw :D

Comment: Finally, happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple overrides of the getFormattedValue in ValueFormatter, so the solution for me was this one:

```
**data_or_axis**.setValueFormatter(new ValueFormatter() {
    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value) {
        return months[(int)value];
    }
});
```

Bests